# Spring JSP form:input tag puts commas in int value

Tags: spring, jsp

Using Spring 2.5 tag library,

I have an Integer value in a command form that's rendered on my page using <form:input path="budget" htmlEscape="true" />

When the value is > 999, it renders the number as value="x,xxx" on the page. My validation isn't expecting the comma and rejects the value.

Is there a fix for the rendering, or do I need to fix the validation and parsing?

Comment: More information:  It appears that the Spring tag library is using a default PropertyEditor to convert the Integer to and from a string, so it can be customized for locale.

While technically it seems possible to create a custom PropertyEditor to do this, it's horribly complex!

Assuming that the PropertyEditor works coming in as well as going out, it seems like the right thing to do is to just allow commas in the number input.

I'm amazed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, I was just being blind, and discovered that there was a custom property editor bound to the command form in the controller.  It was causing the input field to render with commas.

That would have been fine, if there also wasn't a JavaScript validation that rejected the field for having commas in it.